# Slackware cifs mount - how to control permissions?

Tags: permissions, cifs, slackware

Using a NAS device which provides samba/smb services, mounts to a Slackware box work, but the ownership is root, and users don't have permission to write.

So:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.12/NAS1 /u/NAS1 -o rw, user=joeuser,password=passjoe,domain=MYSMBGROUP
```

Mounts with /u/NAS1 with a uid,gid of root,root and users cannot write or create directories on the NAS.  I have looked around with google and cannot find this exact situation with a solution. On Slackware 14, it appears that only root can mount.

I also tried using file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775, and was still unable to create files or directories.

My question is, how do I control the mounted uid,gid, so that I can have users in the gid write to the drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why, but I *did* get the right response when I did:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.2/NAS1 /u/NAS1 -o uid=100,gid=100
```

The NAS is now mounted with that user,group, and I will work on permissions so that group members can modify.  I guess I just asked too early in my frustration process.  (grin)